# Windows API editbox reflecting SendMessage

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface

I am trying to learn windows API.  I have managed to create a window with a button and an edit box.  I wanted to try and change the text in the editbox when I click the button.

Here is main loop:

```
while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
```

Here is windows call back

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        {


            HWND hWndEdit   = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                                    "EDIT","",
                                    WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOVSCROLL|ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
                                    50,100,200,100,hwnd,
                                    (HMENU) IDC_EDITBOX,
                                    GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                                    NULL);

            HWND hWndButton = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                                "BUTTON",
                                "OK",
                                WS_TABSTOP|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
                                50, 220, 100, 24, hwnd,
                                (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON,
                                GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                                NULL);

        }
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDC_BUTTON:
            {
                SendMessage(hWndEdit,WM_SETTEXT,NULL,(LPARAM)"BUTTON");
            }
            break;
        case IDC_EDITBOX:
        {
            MessageBox(NULL,"EDIT","editbox", MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_OK);

        }
        break;
        default:
            MessageBox(NULL,"default","Command",MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_OK);
            break;

        }
        break;

    case WM_SETTEXT:
        {
                MessageBox(NULL,"SetTEXT","BOX",MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_OK);

        }
            break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
    default:

        return DefWindowProc(hwnd,msg,wParam,lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I click the button, I call `SendMessage(...)` so shouldn't that be picked up in my main loop and sent to `WndProc()`?  If so, then why aren't my switch cases catching it?  If not, how do I go about setting up callback functions for this edit box?

EDIT: Full Code

```
#include <windows.h>


#define IDC_BUTTON 101
#define IDC_EDITBOX 102

HWND hWndEdit;

const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";

//Step 4: the Window Proc
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        {


            HWND hWndEdit   = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                                    "EDIT","",
                                    WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOVSCROLL|ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
                                    50,100,200,100,hwnd,
                                    (HMENU) IDC_EDITBOX,
                                    GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                                    NULL);

            HWND hWndButton = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                                "BUTTON",
                                "OK",
                                WS_TABSTOP|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
                                50, 220, 100, 24, hwnd,
                                (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON,
                                GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                                NULL);

        }
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDC_BUTTON:
            {
                //MessageBox(NULL,"EDIT","editbox", MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_OK);
                SendMessage(hWndEdit,WM_SETTEXT,NULL,(LPARAM)"BUTTON");
            }
            break;
        case IDC_EDITBOX:
        {
            MessageBox(NULL,"EDIT","editbox", MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_OK);

        }
        break;
        default:
            MessageBox(NULL,"default","Command",MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_OK);
            break;

        }
        break;

    case WM_SETTEXT:
        {
                MessageBox(NULL,"SetTEXT","BOX",MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_OK);

        }
            break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
    default:

        return DefWindowProc(hwnd,msg,wParam,lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    //Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    //Creating the Window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        //WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        g_szClassName,
        "Inventory",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 400, 300,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    // Step 3: The Message Loop
    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }

    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your calls to `CreateWindowEx()` are assigning the returned `HWND`s to **local variables** that go out of scope when `WM_CREATE` is done being processed.  Your `WM_COMMAND` handler is using an `hWndEdit` variable from a different scope, but that variable is never being initialized with the `HWND` of the edit control.  That is why your text never appears.

Regarding `WM_SETTEXT`, your main window will not receive that message.  It is sent directly to the edit control, which does not have a custom `WndProc()` assigned to it, so all messages sent to it will go through `DefWindowProc()`.  You can send `WM_SETTEXT` to the edit control, and it will be updated (by `DefWindowProc()`) as expected, but your `MessageBox()` will not appear.  An edit control does send `WM_COMMAND` messages to its parent window for various `EN_...` notifications, like `EN_CHANGE`, so your main window `WndProc()` will call `MessageBox()` for `WM_COMMAND` messages related to `IDC_EDITBOX`.

Comment: I declare HWND hWndEdit globally.  Sorry I didn't post full code.

Comment: You might have declared a **global** variable named `hWnEdit`, but the code you did show is clearly declaring a **local** variable named `hWdEdit` as well. That code is assigning the result of `CreateWindowEx()` to the **local** variable, not to any **global** variable.

Comment: `HWND hWndEdit;` - this is a global variable. `**HWND** hWndEdit = ...;` is declaring and assigning a local variable.  Remove the duplicate `HWND` to eliminate the local variable and assign to the global variable instead: `/*HWND*/ hWndEdit = ...;`

Comment: doh, what a noob mistake.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each `HWND` object has its own window procedure to handle the messages for that window. Your `WndProc` is associated with the main window, not the edit text window or the button window. This is why you are not trapping the `WM_SETTEXT` message -- `DispatchMessage` is sending it to the window procedure of the edit control.

The controls send `WM_COMMAND` (for user32 controls) or `WM_NOTIFY` (for commctrl controls) notifications to the parent window (e.g. button clicks) so the parent window can handle events from those controls without subclassing the control.

I don't know if there is a callback associated with `WM_SETTEXT` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775458%28v=vs.85%29.aspx in the Notifications section for a list of supported notifications), so you may need to subclass the child controls.

Comment: The `WndProc()` is associated with the button's parent window, so `WndProc()` will receive the button's `WM_COMMAND` message, and thus can update the edit. That is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
HWND hWndEdit   = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                                    "EDIT","",
                                    WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOVSCROLL|ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
                                    50,100,200,100,hwnd,
                                    (HMENU) IDC_EDITBOX,
                                    GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                                    NULL);
```

To

```
hWndEdit   = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                                    "EDIT","",
                                    WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOVSCROLL|ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
                                    50,100,200,100,hwnd,
                                    (HMENU) IDC_EDITBOX,
                                    GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                                    NULL);
```

No need to redeclare hWndEdit since you already declared the handle globally